# I Want to draw a hierarchial tree in a browser

Tags: html, css, browser, hierarchical-trees

I want to draw a hierarchial tree in a browser. I have used CSS and HTML and Javascript to play with some basic UI stuff in Browser. But I want to draw cool nodes and awesome connectors and come up with an aesthetic hierarchial tree (not Windows Explorer Folder tree).

At this point the nodes in the tree will be like the flash-cards that we use to study say the GRE word list. They need not be editable.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to have a look at [Slickmap](http://astuteo.com/slickmap/).